# How to fill empty cell value in pandas with condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, row

My sample dataset is as below. Actuall data till 2020 is available.

```
    Item  Year    Amount  final_sales
    A1    2016    123     400
    A2    2016    23      40
    A3    2016    6       
    A4    2016    10      100
    A5    2016    5       200
    A1    2017    123     400
    A2    2017    23      
    A3    2017    6       
    A4    2017    10      
    A5    2017    5       200
```

I have to extrapolate 2017 (and subsequent years) `final_sales` column data from 2016 for every Item if 2017 data not available.
In the above dataset `final_sales` not available for the year 2017 for  A2 and A4 but available for 2016 year. How to bring in 2016 data (final_sales) value if corresponding year final_sales not available?

Expected results as below. Thanks.

```
    Item  Year    Amount  final_sales
    A1    2016    123     400
    A2    2016    23      40
    A3    2016    6       
    A4    2016    10      100
    A5    2016    5       200
    A1    2017    123     400
    A2    2017    23      40
    A3    2017    6       
    A4    2017    10      100
    A5    2017    5       200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to fill forward where there is missing data.

You can do this with 'fillna', which is available on pd.DataFrame objects.

In your case, you only want to fill forward for each item, so first group by item, and then use fillna. The method 'pad' just carries forward in order (hence why we sort first).

```
df['final_sales'] = df.sort_values('Year').groupby('Item')['final_sales'].fillna(method='pad')
```

Note that on your example data, A3 is missing for 2016 as well, so there is nothing to carry forward and it remains missing for 2017.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, if A3 is missing for 2016, it will not be carried over. I will try

Comment: Depending on your pandas version, you may need to use sort_values instead of sort

Comment: Brilliant idea. Thanks. I din't think of that way :) Yes I had to use ```sort_values```

Answer (score 0):

For me working [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html), only necessary sorted `Year` column like in question sample data:

```
#if necessary sorting by both columns
df = df.sort_values(['Year', 'Item'])
df['final_sales'] = df.groupby('Item')['final_sales'].ffill()
print (df)
  Item  Year  Amount  final_sales
0   A1  2016     123        400.0
1   A2  2016      23         40.0
2   A3  2016       6          NaN
3   A4  2016      10        100.0
4   A5  2016       5        200.0
5   A1  2017     123        400.0
6   A2  2017      23         40.0
7   A3  2017       6          NaN
8   A4  2017      10        100.0
9   A5  2017       5        200.0
```

Comment: Guess ordering is required as the items list are random and not like example shown.

Comment: @Lilly - hmm, then use `df = df.sort_values(['Year', 'Item'])`

Comment: No need to sort by 'Item' if you are grouping by 'Item'

Comment: @tim654321 - hmmm, maybe miss [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705732/how-to-fill-empty-cell-value-in-pandas-with-condition/58707844?noredirect=1#comment103710537_58707844)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
    def fill_final(x):
        if x['year'] != 2016:
            return df[(df['year'] == 2016) & (df['Item'] == x['Item'])]['final_sales']
        else: return x['final_sales']
    df['final_sales'] = df.apply(lambda x: fill_final(x), axis = 1)
```

did not test this but should set you on the right path